# SBT 0.13.7 and Scala 2.11.5 version compatibility issues

Tags: scala, compilation, compiler-errors, sbt, scala-2.11

Trying out sbt version 0.13.7 with scala version 2.11.5. Both are the newest right now. Do they work together? When I run `sbt clean compile`, it prints:

```
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.11.5. Compiling...
error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Infer$Inferencer
```

When changed to scala 2.11.4, it is all ok:

```
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.11.4. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 13.434 s
```

I could not find any relevant sources about sbt and scala version compatibility. Could it be related to [Does sbt build against scala 2.11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282469/does-sbt-builds-againts-scala-2-11/23283286) ?

Comment: I'm using these versions without problem. You could try to remove your local cache, sometimes this is in bad state in my experience: `rm -r ~/.sbt/boot/ && rm -r ~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang && rm -r ~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-sbt/`

Comment: Yeah, that solved it ! I am using IntelliJ, so maybe it caused this chaos in the cache...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try to remove your local cache, sometimes this is in bad state in my experience:

```
rm -r ~/.sbt/boot/
rm -r ~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/
rm -r ~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-sbt/
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will be better

```
rm -rf ~/.sbt/boot/
rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/
rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-sbt/
```

If this failed, run activator several times.