# sbt run: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1

Tags: scala, sbt

I follow the tutorial of [sbt Hello World](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Hello.html), and I mkdir with hw.scala and build.sbt in it.

then I type `sbt run` and execute it, then occur a error

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1`

But if I change the `scalaVersion` in build.sbt, for example, I change it to `2.11.7` and it will be successful output "Hi" with the example code.

How to solve this error? Thanks everyone helping me.

the error:

- [info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.11.8. Compiling...
- [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#interface;0.13.13 ...
- [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:compileIncremental for 
  the full output.
- [error] (compile:compileIncremental) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1

and my code `build.sbt`, `hw.scala`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "hello",
    version := "0.1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
  )
```

-

```
object Hi { def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hi!") }
```

Comment: Code you posted works fine for me

Comment: @dlite922 I delete .ivy2/ and .sbt/ and reinstall sbt, then I try it again, it also have this error. My laptop is ubuntu 16.04 and I also install scala 2.12.0 from [http://www.scala-lang.org/download/](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/)

Comment: It could be mismatched versions of sbt and scala. Make sure your sbt version and scala version get along

Comment: @dlite922 e.., now I haven't found the solution, my sbt version is 0.13.13, is this version not compatible with scala 2.11.8 ? is this can related to [Does sbt build against scala 2.11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282469/does-sbt-build-against-scala-2-11/)?

Comment: I ran your code with SBT 0.13.8 and Scala 2.11.7, so something else might be wrong with your system. Could you try it on a virtual box ubuntu?

Comment: I will try it, thanks for you help^_^