# When is there a sbt version for 2.13?

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to develop a ***sbt plugin*** that has dependencies that are only available for ***Scala 2.13***.

I found on https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5032 this list:

> - SBT 0.x runs only on Scala 2.10.x
> - SBT 1.x runs only on Scala 2.12.x
> - SBT 2.x will run only on Scala 2.13.x or 3.0.x
> - SBT 3.x will run only on Scala 3.0.x or Scala 3.1.x

Where the last two lines was a guess by the author *mr-git*.

However I did not find any other glue if there is actually a version for *Scala 2.13*.

Does anybody know?

**Update**: Added it here: https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/when-is-there-a-sbt-version-for-2-13/5623

Comment: What particular dependencies do you miss? Perhaps it would be possible to backport them to 2.12?

Comment: @Suma thanks - it is our own source code which is 2.13 / we use some of the new features of 2.13

Comment: You probably already know this, but be sure to use https://github.com/scala/scala-collection-compat - this enables some 2.13 features on 2.12. The only thing which really required me to write version specific code were custom collections and even that was doable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If afraid you are out of luck. Your plugin needs to be binary compatible with the SBT, which currently means 2.12 for SBT 1.x.x or 2.10 for SBT 0.13.x. There is no trace of any SBT 2 version anywhere on the Internet, certainly no such version exists in the [SBT GitHub repository](https://github.com/sbt/sbt)

The situation was similar with Scala 2.11 before, see [Does sbt build against scala 2.11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282469/does-sbt-build-against-scala-2-11) and [What's the relationship of the versions of scala when I use sbt to build a scala project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49000201/whats-the-relationship-of-the-versions-of-scala-when-i-use-sbt-to-build-a-scala)